Blazor StreamRendering already not working in sample project
I am new to Blazor and started with a YouTube tutorial.
Therefore I created a Blazor Web App project in VS 2022 (latest version) and .NET Runtime 8.0.6. I included the sample code (Weather App) in the project and let it run without changing anything of the sample code.


As i open the Weather Tab, it is supposed to instantly open the weather page, display "Loading..." for 500ms and show a table with some temperatures afterwards. In my case it waits the 500ms before opening the weater tab and instantly shows the table.
Here is the code of the blazor sample file:
@page "/weather"
@attribute [StreamRendering]

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Simulate asynchronous loading to demonstrate streaming rendering
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        }).ToArray();
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}

Therefore the @attribute [StreamRendering] is not working because it does not run the OnInitializedAsync() method asynchronously on the server side.
There is also a GitHub post showing the exact same issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52323.
This one is more related to the issue of IIS compressing and does not contain a solution for me. In my case it does not work with http, https or IIS either.
It also does not matter which Browser I use and it is also not working on my colleagues PC.
I am already frustrated before I even started with Blazor...

It does seem like streaming rendering is a new feature that isn't quite stable yet and depends on several settings in IIS and the app itself.

There are some limitiation when using IIS Express/IIS, please try to use HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>().DisableBuffering();.

I have faced some similiar issue last week, please kindly ckeck it https://stackoverflow.com/a/78680548/7687666

@JasonPan where whould I need to put that code? Also I am not using the IIS but https...

What is the hosting environment for your site?  Kestrel, IIS Express....?

Just tried the same as you and it works (I also made the Task.Delay longer to make sure) - suggest you try adding this to the page to check the runtime version is what you expect <span>Running under .NET @Environment.Version</span>

Also check dotnet --version in the project folder to check the SDK version

Hi Weiß Brot, the official sample code seems not correct, and I change it like below, it works now. If you face any other issue(like host it in windows and not works), please let me know.

The standard template code works exactly as it should. Your problem is Not Reproducable.

@JasonPan what you call similar issue is completely unrelated. Just returning IAsyncEnumerable doesn't mean you have a real streaming response which requires WebSockets or gRPC. It means your code is writing individual JSON fragments to the output stream and yes, buffering does affect how often the data is written to the stream. In Blazor though, SignalR is used to send changes to the browser

@PanagiotisKanavos After looking at the issue on github, I was clear about the crux of the issue, mainly to see why there was no loading... prompt, so I chose to update the answer instead of deleting the previous reply.

UPDATE
After testing, I can reproduce the issue when using vs2022 v17.8.1.
My test steps:
I uninstall my latest vs2022 and install vs2022 v17.8.1 (sdk 8.0.100).
Solution
So please update your vs2022 to latest version and use the latest .net core SDK.

After my investigation, I found the usage of await Task.Delay(2000); in sample project is wrong. It means the application will hold on 2 seconds, then the data will show in the page.
So I custom the GenerateForecastsAsync method to generate the data per 2 seconds. Here is the completely code and it works for me.
@page "/weather"
@attribute [StreamRendering]

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private List<WeatherForecast> forecasts = [];

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
         var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        // forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        // {
        //     Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
        //     TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        //     Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        // }).ToArray();
        await foreach (var weather in GenerateForecastsAsync(startDate, summaries, 5))
        {
            forecasts.Add(weather);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
    private async IAsyncEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GenerateForecastsAsync(DateOnly startDate, string[] summaries, int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            yield return new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = startDate.AddDays(i),
                    TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
                };

            await Task.Delay(2000); // Optional throttling to prevent overwhelming UI
        }
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}


You do show an enhanced version of StreamRendering with the IAsyncEnumerable. But none of this should be needed. The plain template code works Ok over here.

Thanks for the answer. But the await Task.Delay(2000); Should not be wrong as it is already there in the plain template (with 500ms). I also tried your solution which did not fix the issue as it now takes 2 secs for each entry in the weather table before opening the weather page. (At least in my case. May be different with working streamrendering)

Hi @WeißBrot, After my testing, I reproduce the issue, please kindly check my updates.

Hi @WeißBrot The latest version (v17.10.3) is working fine, please try it, waiting for your test result.

This answer doesn't really reproduce a problem with StreamRendering. Web apps aren't executed by Visual Studio. Visual Studio is the debugger. If the application is paused, it can't send anything to the browser. There may be an issue in the debugger but that doesn't mean Stream Rendering doesn't work. A real problem would be running the application with dotnet run or Ctrl+F5 and still getting delays. That's why people are saying this can't be reproduced

Hi @PanagiotisKanavos Have you checked my answer carefully? I have tested it on a brand new machine, please comment after testing, thanks. It seems a bit rude to comment directly without testing.

Thanks @Json Pan. I already had the latest VS Version installed (17.10.3) and the latest .net sdk (8.0.302). Just in case I uninstalled VS and reinstalled again. Same issue...

Hi @WeißBrot, how about using another PC, I mean maybe you can let your team mates or friends try it. This issue is machine-related.

Hi @Json Pan, that is a good idea. However we already tried it on 3 different machines from my team mates at work. We all have the same issue. Basically the OS, VS and Browsers are the same.

Hi @WeißBrot Could you share your OS version ?

Hi @Jason Pan, yes: Windows 10 Version 22H2 Build 19045.4529

Hi @WeißBrot Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this problem in the new environment. Would you mind trying to publish this default template project and see if you encounter the same problem in the windows server? If the problem cannot be reproduced, it can be proved that the problem is related to the machine (possibly related to company policies).
